# C: Combining while and if statements

Tags: c, function, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program in C which calls one of two functions, based on the input provided by the user.

The program should say "you selected A" if the user enters '1', and "you selected B" if the user enters '2'. The problem I have is that the message "you selected A" is returned whether the user enters 1 or 2 (see screenshots).

[Selection 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCorb.png)

[Selection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLz51.png)

Here is my code:

```
include <stdio.h>

void celsiusFahrenheit()
{
    printf("You chose A");
}

void fahrenheitCelsius()
{
    printf("You chose B");
}

int main()
{
    int selection;
    printf("Please enter '1' to convert celsius to fahrenheit, or enter '2' to convert fahrenheit to celsius: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &selection);
    while (selection < 1 || selection > 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid entry of either 1 or 2: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &selection);
    }
    if (selection = 1)
    {
        celsiusFahrenheit();
    }
    else
    {
        fahrenheitCelsius();
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help you can give!

Comment: `selection = 1` is an assignment not an equality comparison ( `==` ). If you had compiled with some defensive flags (like `-Wall` for gcc/clang) your compiler would've warned you about it.

Comment: Change `if (selection = 1)` to `if (selection == 1)`. This is such a common mistake. Increase compiler warnings and maybe code as `if (1 == selection)` to produce an error if typed incorrectly.

Comment: @PSkocik Clang has `-Weverything`.

Comment: Thanks, guys. That's really helpful!

Comment: @FiddlingBits: `-Weverything` warns about too much — I don't regard it as usable on production code, because it complains, for example, if you enable POSIX functionality with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` because the name is reserved for the implementation.  Yes, I know it is; that's why I used it!  It has to be tuned to be really usable with a number of `-Wno-xyz` options.  I use `-Weverything -Wno-padded -Wno-vla -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-documentation-unknown-command` to make things work sanely enough for me.  I also use `-Werror` so I don't compile with any warnings allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an integer constant to an integer (`selection = 1`) and checking its truth value and it will **always** be true.
As already pointed out in the comments, you can use the `-Wall` option which will warn you,

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

 if (selection = 1)

     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Or change the `if` conditional like this:

```
 if (1 == selection)
```

If you had made the same mistake (assignment) in the above statement, the compiler would generate an error even without `-Wall` option and you would have avoided this bug in your program.